# After attaching google private service connect I am unable to delete VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I was playing around with private service connect in gcp, and I attached an endpoint with an IP to enable private access to all google apis. I wanted to tear this down and build up this configuration in terraform, however I am unable to delete the entry in my GCP Networking Service Directory. It states this type of connection cannot be deleted. Does this mean I am unable to delete my VPC and recreate it? It seems like all of the resources cannot be deleted, and my VPC won't delete due to a forwarding rule. I am getting the following error messages:

"This type of service cannot be deleted"

"This type of namespace cannot be deleted"

"Endpoints belonging to non-user-defined service cannot be deleted"

And this error message when attempting to delete the vpc:

"The address resource 'projects/x/global/addresses/endpoints' is already being used by 'projects/x/global/forwardingRules/endpoint'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deleting a Private Service Connect endpoint:**
To perform this task, you must have following permissions or all the following IAM roles.

**Permissions:**

```
compute.globalForwardingRules.pscDelete  
compute.globalForwardingRules.delete  
servicedirectory.namespaces.delete  
dns.managedZones.delete
```

**Roles:**
All the following roles:

```
Compute Network Admin (roles/compute.networkAdmin),  
Service Directory Editor (roles/servicedirectory.editor), and  
DNS Administrator (roles/dns.admin)
```

**Using Console:**
Go to Console -> Network Services -> Private Service Connect -> Click the “Connected endpoints” tab -> Select the Private Service Connect endpoint you want to delete, and click **Delete**.

**Using gcloud:**
Run the following command in the cloud shell.

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules delete **ENDPOINT_NAME** --global
```

For more information refer to the documentation [deleting a Private Service Connect endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-service-connect-apis#delete-endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Just found it it was "Private Service Connect" And I was able to delete the endpoint there..

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the Routes & VPC peering manual